# How to get rangy startContainer as a real string?

Tags: javascript, rangy

I'm using rangy to get a selection from a div; it's working. What I now want is to get the contents of the selection's startContainer property as a real string, so that I can embed it into a hidden field in a form.  A brief hack at my rangy code looks like this:

```
range_zero = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
console.log(rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer);
```

The console.log is there to show me that I'm getting the value and, in the console, it looks right.  But when I insert it into a form, with something like:

```
$('form#my_form .the_field').val(rangy.getSelection.startContainer);
```

I get:

```
<input class="the_field" type="hidden" value="[object Text]">
```

I've tried hanging .toString() calls everywhere imaginable (including ...startContainer.toString()), but I keep coming up with [object Text].  Any advice out there?

(btw, I'm a total rangy noob, if that's not obvious.  My general javascript competence is somewhat better....)

Comment: Not certain what expected result is? An HTML element as a string?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the text inside the startContainer, as a string.